# Drag a UIButton or a UIImage without subclassing

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, drag

I have a custom controller and inside I have a UIImageView ( or a UIButton ). My custom controller is a slider, so basically when touchesEnded is called I want to check the intersection with other components. I can't manage to drag the UIImageView, and if I subclass it, I will have to write all the logic code in the subclass of UIIMage and I don't want that. Is there a way to drag it from my custom controller class?

Thank you.

Comment: CGRectIntersectsRect (CGRect rect1, CGRect rect2); use this if two rect/frame intersect or not..

Comment: Yes, but this code I have to write it in my UIImageView subclass, and I don't want that. I want to have all the logic of my custom controller in the UIControl subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to let each element to [manage its own touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707858/basic-drag-and-drop-in-ios/). So the drags in the `UIImageView` is independent of other events of the parent view.

Comment: Yes, but I need to check if the UImageView intersects with other components in the control, this means that I have to keep a reference of my control in my UImageView subclass. I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

You will most definetly not have to write *"all the logic code"*, that's what subclassing is all about.

So to answer your question not in way you want it but in a way you will have the least work to do:

consider subclassing again. You only have to override three methods and add one iVar.

Please see both answers here: [UIView drag (image and text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982277/uiview-drag-image-and-text/8332581#8332581)

Comment: I did something else. I use a UIPanGestureRecognizer, and my UIButton is the only one that will accept touches for the gesture recognizer.

Comment: `    -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (touch.view == sliderButton)
        return YES;
    return NO;
}`