# Xcode object moving towards finger im new here

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, ios5

Hi guys I am preety new here.
And I have a `UIimageview`.
And I know what is the coordinates of a `UITouch`.
Now I want the ball(`UIImageView`) to go towards it.
I tried to think of ways to do this...
Using `CGPoint`
But I cant think on any way that will work properly
How can I do that? (i didnt found answer in the internet)

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self play];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(play) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    ballvelocity = [touch locationInView:self.view];

}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    ballvelocity = [touch locationInView:self.view];

}

-(void) play{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
        ball.center = CGPointMake(ballvelocity.x, ballvelocity.y);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried. It's expected on Stack Overflow that you will show some effort and we will help you from there.

Answer (score 1):

if you are good with block..

you can create a animation with

```
UIView animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval) animations:^(void)>
```

other wise

```
UIView beginAnimations:(NSString *) context:(void *)
```

in both the animation methods you can set

```
[imageView setCenter:yourlocation];
```

this will animate it to the position.

**more info on animating views here :**
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816

Comment: hmm will it work if the position of the touch is always changing?

Comment: no problem..google UIView beginAnimations tutorials...i will be able to solve your problems...but putting a full fledged tutorials here. which are widely available on internet is silly..dont worry about the block one..you will learn its advantage eventually..dont focus on it now,

Comment: @user1232989: if you want to be able to drag the view with your finger then check both answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982277/uiview-drag-image-and-text/8332581#8332581

Comment: yeah..a new lesson to you..alwasys try to search your problem on google and stack overflow first..

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! im checking it and will tell you if it works thank you very much :)

Comment: ok I looked in the web and did this:[UIView beginAnimation:nil context:nil];  [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];  [UIView setAnimationDuration:3];  [ball setCenter:CGPointMake(ballvelocity.x, ballvelocity.y)];  [UIView commitAnumations]; and the ball just jump to the position of the touch i want it to "walk" to it

Comment: by the way i've putted that^^^^ inside of -(void)touchesMoved

Comment: your uiview animation code is getting called repeatedly..in touches moved..i will suggest making a counter to make the animation called only once ...and reset the counter...basically you can set a delegate method of the animation..which is called after the animation is completed...reset the counter there..search for animation delgae..

Comment: i have set a timer for that... its not updating this: [ball setCenter:CGPointMake(ballvelocity.x, ballvelocity.y)]; i updated the x and y of the ball velocity while the animation is working and its not updating in the animation what can i do?

Comment: try [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0] .. what you are experiencing shouldn't really be there...update the question with your code..

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(play) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
ballvelocity = [touch locationInView:self.view];

}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
ballvelocity = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    
}

-(void) play{
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
ball.center = CGPointMake(ballvelocity.x, ballvelocity.y);

Comment: sorry for the mess^ hope you understand something

Comment: some simple debugging steps..change duration to 3.0 , make the timer autorepeat to NO ... try to amok a simple new project and try the animation with some random values..like set center:CGPointMake(160,240) .. rather than your touch.. you will see different results and then you will get the idea what might be a problem