# iPhone: Drag to make a new object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

Im making an iPad app that will have some objects on the screen in a menu area. I want the user to be able to touch down and drag from one of these objects to place a new copy of that object on the view.

To further explain, say I have a checkers chip on the side of the UIView in the "game piece" / menu area. I want the user to touch down and drag from that checkers piece to drag a new checker piece onto the game board. I dont want the original checker to move, its just a place holder, but I want to create a new object that is dragged from the first checker.

I see a couple of ways to do that however I cant figure out how to do it without the user picking up their finger to reselect the new game piece. I want the new piece to be drag able immediately after touching the first place holder object.

Any ideas? Please and thank you for the assistance.

Comment: You coul'd always have two copies of view on of top on eachother. When the top one is dragged away (you know that on touchesMoved:) you simply create a third one (which is created on original position under or on top of the one that stayed on it's original place)

Comment: And if you're looking for dragging code it's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982277/uiview-drag-image-and-text/8332581#8332581

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this before by creating a copy of the `UIView` that I wish to move, then using the `UIResponder` API (`touchesBegan`, etc.) to move the new copy in its superview based on the drag gesture translation, thereby leaving the original "menu" view *in situ*.  Does this make sense?

When you create the moveable copy, you can set its alpha or create a border or some other visual confection to indicate the provisional nature of the drag object.

Comment: Thank you Im going to try that out. I'll let you know how it goes :)

Comment: It's a lot of code; so hard to post more than skeletal answer.

Comment: I would decide to do something complicated. :)