# Xcode: Label making error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, window

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, 45, 140, 21);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    [window addSubview:label];
    [label setText:@"Hello world"];
    [label release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

The error is: Use of underclared identifier 'window'

Comment: There is no reason to create new reference like `UITouch *touchX`, you can use first one every time.

Comment: There's an elegant solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982277/uiview-drag-image-and-text/8332581#8332581 It involves subclassing but that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the **tag** property of `UIImageView` of each one of the letters and check against them on touchesMoved.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent: (UIEvent*)event{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view.superview];

    switch (touch.view.tag) {
        case 0:
            a.center=location;
            break;
        case 1:
            b.center=location;
            break;
        case 3:
            c.center=location;
            break;
    }
}
```

### Edit

Using @beryllium 's comment:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent: (UIEvent*)event{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view.superview];
    touch.view.center = location;
}
```

Also note that you should get the images' superview location, and not from the image itself.

Comment: @beryllium comment makes sense, my answer is valid if you want to treat the touched views differently.