# Target action is called twice

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a VC RaceDayChecklistViewController.m which is subclass of RaceDayChecklistViewControllerBase.m.

In RaceDayChecklistVC.m , added a target action which is getting called twice. nextOrNewButton is the button on click of which i want to invoke "demo" action.
Also ,checklistnavigationItem is the bar  Button item.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    checklistTableViewBase=checklistTableView;
   checklistNavigationItemBase=checklistnavigationItem;
    nextOrNewButtonBase=nextOrNewButton;

    [nextOrNewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(demo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];

}

-(void) demo
{
    RaceDayDataController *sharedController = [RaceDayDataController sharedDataController];

    if (sharedController.isSubmited)
    {
        [self.checklistnavigationItem setTitle:@"New"]; //
    }
    else
    {
        [self.checklistnavigationItem setTitle:@"Next"];
        [self showAlert];
    }
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [nextOrNewButton removeTarget:self action: @selector(demo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
}
```

What could be the reason for multiple call to the action demo? Is it the base class responsible some how?

pls guide.

Comment: no its the only place where i used.. @mani

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UIButton` generates multiple events while pressing: usually they are `UIControlEventTouchDownInside` and `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. So, if you want to handle press, you should catch the one you need (probably `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`), not `UIControlEventsAll`.

Answer (score 2):

I can see this

```
[nextOrNewButton removeTarget:self action: @selector(demo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
```

That means, When you touch the button,`touch up` event(`UIControlEventTouchUpInside`) trigger, so it will fire one time. After that, `touch down` will happen, so it will fire again with `UIControlEventTouchDownInside` .

So you can use this,

```
[nextOrNewButton removeTarget:self action: @selector(demo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

**You are listening about all events, so you are getting all events.**

Normally to capture the button tap event we would have **UIControlEventTouchUpInside**.

[Here is the option for you.](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlEvents)

```
        typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIControlEvents) {
            UIControlEventTouchDown           = 1 <<  0,      // on all touch downs
            UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat     = 1 <<  1,      // on multiple touchdowns (tap count > 1)
            UIControlEventTouchDragInside     = 1 <<  2,
            UIControlEventTouchDragOutside    = 1 <<  3,
            UIControlEventTouchDragEnter      = 1 <<  4,
            UIControlEventTouchDragExit       = 1 <<  5,
            UIControlEventTouchUpInside       = 1 <<  6,
            UIControlEventTouchUpOutside      = 1 <<  7,
            UIControlEventTouchCancel         = 1 <<  8,

            UIControlEventValueChanged        = 1 << 12,     // sliders, etc.

            UIControlEventEditingDidBegin     = 1 << 16,     // UITextField
            UIControlEventEditingChanged      = 1 << 17,
            UIControlEventEditingDidEnd       = 1 << 18,
            UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit = 1 << 19,     // 'return key' ending editing

            UIControlEventAllTouchEvents      = 0x00000FFF,  // for touch events
            UIControlEventAllEditingEvents    = 0x000F0000,  // for UITextField
            UIControlEventApplicationReserved = 0x0F000000,  // range available for application use
            UIControlEventSystemReserved      = 0xF0000000,  // range reserved for internal framework use
            UIControlEventAllEvents           = 0xFFFFFFFF
        };
```

Comment: what is most appropriate..Its the first time i am using  target..can you pls guide.. i have to just click the button and move..

Comment: @Lalit_vicky You'll probably want to use `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.

Comment: @Lalit_vicky Please you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856906/touchesbegan-touchesended-touchesmoved-for-moving-uiview

Answer (score 0):

As you set `UIControlEventAllEvents` thats why when you touch your button it takes two type of touch so you should use only one type of `Event` either `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` or `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`.

```
[nextOrNewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(demo) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```